# Jquery news ticker looping

Tags: jquery

Below is my Jquery news ticker.I want to loop it.so that news ticker will not stop and it moves continously.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#ticker").animate({ "left": "-420px" }, 1000, 'linear');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I will not write the code for you. But when your animation finishes, you want it to go back to it's original position and re-call the function that animates it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
function ticker() {

  $(".ticker").animate({ 
    "right": parseInt($('.ticker').css('right')) + 20 + 'px' 
  }, 1000, 'linear', ticker);

}

ticker()
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v8p0efzx/1/)