# News Ticker Looping

Tags: jquery

I want to loop this code because this is news ticker and i want to run repeatdly.kindly help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>News Ticker</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px">
<div style="background-color: #CCCCCC; width: 100%; height: 40px">
<span id="ticker" style="left: 120%; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top:10px;   width: 30%">This is a text</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#ticker").animate({ "left": "-420px" }, 1000, 'linear', ticker);

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you read about `setInterval` ? your'e might also need a reset location code. just repeating it - won't help much

Comment: You asked the exact same question 3 hours ago.. possible duplicate of [Jquery news ticker looping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831529/jquery-news-ticker-looping)

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there. There are just a few things to address:

- You need to put your animation method inside a function, so it can be called again. You then need to call that function initially.
- You need to reset the `left` property of your `<span>`, so it doesn't continue to go `-420px` left everytime.
- You (probably) need to give `position:relative` and `overflow:hidden` to the parent to position the `<span>` relative to it's parent, and to hide it when it is not within it's parent's boundaries:

**HTML**

```
<div style="background-color: #CCCCCC; width: 100%; height: 40px; overflow:hidden; position:relative;">
    <span id="ticker" style="left: 120%; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top:10px;   width: 30%">This is a text</span>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var ticker = function(){
    $("#ticker").css({left:"120%"}).animate({ "left": "-420px" }, 1000, 'linear', ticker);
}

ticker();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tLcrdqLh/)